# how to get iphone time

Tags: objective-c

can you help out in finding the iphone time through iphone application

Comment: Press the round button at the bottom of the phone and the time should appear on the screen somewhere near the top

Answer (score 5):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
```

Gives you the current time and date.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];  

NSCalendar *calendar= [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:today];

[calendar release];    

NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour];
NSInteger min = [dateComponents minute];
NSInteger sec = [dateComponents second];
```

This will actually get just the time from the date, not the whole date. It gets the time in separate integers, `hour`, `min`, `sec`. To put them all back together in a string you can do the following:

```
NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i:%i", hour, min, sec];
```

Comment: Don't forget to release your calendar when you're done with it.